# Covariant return type on auto property remains null when initalized in constructor

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I got a problem with auto property initialization with covariant return type.
In the BaseClass constructor, there is no exception but the auto property remains null.

I found a workaround, by overriding the property and make a cast in the body of the get (see in comment below).

Do you have got an explanation of the behavior ? And is there a better workaround ?

Regards,

PS : I made a mistake. Of course, the overridden property must be FinalProperty and not BaseProperty.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        Console.WriteLine(new FinalClass(new FinalProperty()).MyProperty == null); // true
    }
}

public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(BaseProperty prop)
    {
        MyProperty = prop;
        Console.WriteLine($"ctor A : {MyProperty == null}"); // true
    }

    public virtual BaseProperty MyProperty { get; }
}



public class FinalClass : BaseClass
{
    public FinalClass(BaseProperty prop)
        : base(prop)
    { }

    public override FinalProperty MyProperty { get; }

    //public override FinalProperty MyProperty
    //{
    //    get { return (FinalProperty)base.MyProperty; }
    //}
}

public class BaseProperty
{ }

public sealed class FinalProperty : BaseProperty
{ }
```

Comment: It's because you override `MyProperty` in `FinalClass` and you're setting the one in the `BaseClass`.  If you're going to override it then you should set it in the `FinalClass` constructor.  Also there is no covariance here because you're not using generics.

Comment: How is this about covariant return types? `MyProperty` in `FinalClass` has the same type as `MyProperty` in `BaseClass`.

Comment: Specifically the issue is that you are only overriding the `get` so when you set it in the `BaseClass` it's set to a hidden field on that class, but the overriden get in the `FinalClasss` will pull from a new hidden field defined in `FinalClass`

Answer (score 1):

Why this is happening - for every `MyProperty` overriden in child clas using auto property compiler will generate the new backing field for that class i.e. next:

```
public class FinalClass : BaseClass
{
    public FinalClass(FinalProperty prop)
            : base(prop)
    { }

    public override FinalProperty MyProperty { get; }
}
```

Will be [transformed by compiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCDMACciBCBDAzgUwMIBstNZFSzSBvE8m0hNLPQzTACgxwAUAnAewAds3AC4BPRPz78AlNVrkqMecsQBZUTwFCxiALwSpAbjkryICAE5WAEgBEAY2G9uiAIKIAXIgrrNgkeK6+gB2AK74+AC+ttKGiAD08YjC3KHYJsqRsBny9ABuAJYioej4DFxS2uK+lQHeiADm2MJxWUrybdkwOXRIKABiBcGlBESe5UxEPd7TZkiDw/ijLKwLpX5VBgKy7abkXgBGjKyS27NkFIiduyr0vHlC3AUAJtiIa/gbdTVadZdNLSu02uynoKA42C+YmmlxBuSQOFK2GeyDA7yG61qOi8EKhohhVyAA=) into something like:

```
public class FinalClass : BaseClass
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private readonly FinalProperty <MyProperty>k__BackingField;

    public virtual FinalProperty MyProperty
    {
        [PreserveBaseOverrides]
        [CompilerGenerated]
        get
        {
            return <MyProperty>k__BackingField;
        }
    }

    public FinalClass(FinalProperty prop)
        : base(prop)
    {
    }
}
```

So `BaseClass(BaseProperty prop)` invoked by `base(prop)` will set backing field generated for `MyProperty` in `BaseClass` while `FinalClass.MyProperty` will use the one generated for it.

Another possible workaround is to use generics instead of covariant returns:

```cs
public class BaseClass<T> where T: BaseProperty
{
    public BaseClass(T prop)
    {
        MyProperty = prop;
        Console.WriteLine($"ctor A : {MyProperty == null}"); // true
    }
    public T MyProperty { get; }
}

public class FinalClass : BaseClass<FinalProperty>
{
    public FinalClass(FinalProperty prop)
        : base(prop)
    { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you have overridden `MyProperty` in `FinalClass` by doing this:

```
public override FinalProperty MyProperty { get; }
```

The fact that this is an auto-property still creates an extra backing field in `FinalClass`. Let's remove the syntactic sugar of the auto-properties to see what's going on:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(BaseProperty prop)
    {
        // notice that when setting a get-only field in the constructor, 
        // you are actually setting its backing field
        backingFieldMyPropertyInBaseClass = prop;
        Console.WriteLine($"ctor A : {MyProperty == null}"); // true
    }

    private BaseProperty backingFieldMyPropertyInBaseClass;
    public virtual BaseProperty MyProperty { 
        get { return backingFieldMyPropertyInBaseClass; }
    }
}
public class FinalClass : BaseClass
{
    public FinalClass(BaseProperty prop)
        : base(prop)
    { }

    private FinalProperty backingFieldMyPropertyInFinalClass;
    public override FinalProperty MyProperty { 
        get { return backingFieldMyPropertyInFinalClass; }
    }
}
```

Notice how `backingFieldMyPropertyInFinalClass` is never set.

Making `MyProperty` in `FinalClass` return `base.MyProperty` fixes this because `base.MyProperty` actually returns the field you want - `backingFieldMyPropertyInBaseClass`. You can also make it print false in `Main` by setting `MyProperty` in the constructor of `FinalClass`, so that `backingFieldMyPropertyInFinalClass` is set.

Comment: I can't add a protected setter to **MyPpoperty** because covariant return type forbid it.

I set **MyProperty** in the constructor of **FinalClass**, but I would like to be able to use **MyProperty** in **BaseClass** constructor too because it is used by others properties initialized in the base class constructor.

Comment: @R1Tech Well in that case your design is problematic. `BaseClass` _cannot_ safely set the overridden version of `MyProperty`, because you have overridden it with a more specialised type, and `BaseClass` doesn't know what that type is. See the end of Guru Stron's answer for how to let `BaseClass` know what the overridden property type is.

Comment: But I would like to be able to initialize the base property in the base constructor and use it in this constructor then initialize the final property in the final constructor and use it. And the `BaseClass` doesn't know what that type is nor the what type is `MyProperty`.